# How can I run bash command with having Sandbox in Swift?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, swift

I made a working app which hides and shows the desktop icons using bash the terminal command for making it, easier to do this job with an UI, it works ok without sandbox and if there is sandbox it does not.
But the issue is here that According to Apple documentation, to distribute a macOS app through the Mac App Store, you must enable the App Sandbox capability. So if I use and keep Sandbox my code would NOT get processed and I would getting the massage of: "Operation not permitted" so how can I make my codes run with keeping the sandbox?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But even without the actual source code this is basically a software development question. AskDifferent focuses on practical problems of end users.

Comment: Could you please edit my question that be ok for this website, I am new here, thanks

Comment: An edit will not help. Please ask development-related questions on our sister site https://stackoverflow.com